# Is it possible to load Excel sheets' name into MATLAB by using 'xlsread'?

Tags: excel, matlab, file-io

I have 10 Excel files with 50 sheets in each, every sheet has a different name. I want load all sheets' names into MATLAB, put them into a cell string. Is it possible to 'xlsread' command to do this? Or is there other ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`xlsfinfo`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/xlsfinfo.html) to get a list of sheet names in an excel file.

```
[status,sheets] = xlsfinfo(filename)
```

The variable sheets will contain a cell array with the sheet names.